# How to add a placeholder for a Swift Chart that doesn't have any data yet?

Tags: swift, charts

Imagine this chart doesn't have any data.
What api do i use to display a placeholder like "no data yet"?
I've searched WWDC and apple docs.

Maybe it's just a case of hiding the chart and showing some text.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct TopStyleChart: View {
    let data = [
        (name: "Cachapa", sales: 916),
        (name: "Injera", sales: 850),
        (name: "Crêpe", sales: 802),
        (name: "Jian Bing", sales: 753),
        (name: "Dosa", sales: 654),
        (name: "American", sales: 618)
    ]

    var body: some View {
        Chart(data, id: \.name) {
            BarMark(
                x: .value("Sales", $0.sales),
                y: .value("Name", $0.name)
            )
            // Set the foreground style of the bars.
            .foregroundStyle(.pink)
            // Customize the accessibility label and value.
            .accessibilityLabel($0.name)
            .accessibilityValue("\($0.sales) sold")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple if clause should do the trick here:

```
struct TopStyleChart: View {
    let data: [(name: String, sales: Int)]?

    var body: some View {
        if let data = data{
            Chart(data, id: \.name) {
                BarMark(
                    x: .value("Sales", $0.sales),
                    y: .value("Name", $0.name)
                )
                // Set the foreground style of the bars.
                .foregroundStyle(.pink)
                // Customize the accessibility label and value.
                .accessibilityLabel($0.name)
                .accessibilityValue("\($0.sales) sold")
            }
        } else{
            Text("no data yet")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, that's fine...i'm wondering if there is something in the Charts framework that does this. i think i remembering seeing it in WWDC sessions but couldn't find it parsing it today. figured i'd ask.